# How to express " without loss of generality" appropriately?

Tags: article-writing

In my article, I would like to write the following sentence:

> There exisits a vertex in $H$, without loss of generality, let it be
> $v$, such that $H-v$ is connected.

I think the sentence above is incorrect as  two sentences connected by a comma. So I changed it to：

> There is a vertex in $H$; let it be $v$ for the sake of generality, such
> that $H-v$ is connected.

But I feel that  the sentence is not fluent. How can I make my sentence more fluent? I try this:

> There is a vertex in $H$, namely $v$, such
> that $H-v$ is connected.

But this does not seem to reflect the meaning of "without loss of generality".

**Edits:**

PrincessEev's advice is nice. But if I had named $V(H)$ in advance and then wanted to choose $w_1$ without loss of generality, it would have seemed abrupt for me to write that below.

> Let $V(H)$ be $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$. There exists $v_1∈V(H)$ such
> that...

Or:

> "There is a vertex (call it $v_1$) in $H$ such that..."

Comment: I would just say "There is a vertex (call it $v$) in $H$ such that..." or "There exists $v \in V(H)$ such that...", myself. This isn't really a "without loss of generality" situation as much as just giving a name to an entity.

Comment: Thanks. In my article, I have given the names of the vertices of $H$ in advance: $ {v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_n}$, is it OK if I write this: There is a vertex (call it $v_1$) in $H$ such that... ? (The status of each vertices in $v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_n$ is the same.) So I say “without loss of generality... $v_1$” in order to continue the discussion of other vertices ($v_2$, $v_3$, ...) later.

Comment: In that case, absent any other context, I believe that it would be fine. I would write "There is a vertex in $H$ (without loss of generality, let it be $v_1$) such that..." myself in that scenario.

Comment: You could also say. "Renumbering if necessary, we can assume <condition on $v_1$>." Of course, assuming that we somehow know that at least one of the $v_i$ satisfy that condition.

Comment: If you're previously defined $H(V)=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ would write it this way "There exists a vertex $v \in H(V)$ such that $H-v$ is connected. Without loss of generality choose $v_1$." If you haven't defined $H(V)$ yet I would simply say "There exists a $v \in H(V)$ such that $H-v$ is connected" and simply drop the second sentence.